# Retrieving auto generated id in jpa giving null value

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have a Patients entity class which auto generates an id:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "personId", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long personId;

public void copy (Patients patient) {

    if (patient.getNationality() != null)
        this.setNationality(patient.getNationality());
    if (patient.getGivenName() != null)
        this.setGivenName(patient.getGivenName());
    if (patient.getMiddleName() != null)
        this.setMiddleName(patient.getMiddleName());
    if (patient.getPrefix() != null)
        this.setPrefix(patient.getPrefix());

}

 /**
 * @return PERSONID
 */
public int getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}
```

My addPerson in PersonDaoImpl :

```
public Patients addPerson(Patients person) {

    Patients p = new Patients(person);
    try {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-
        dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+05:30");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dateCreated = sdfr.format(date);
        p.setDateCreated(dateCreated);

        em.persist(p);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        log.error("Exception caught :: " + e);
        p = null;
    }

    em.close();
    return p;
}
```

My update api in person service class:

```
@PUT
@Path("/person-manager-resource/updatePersonById")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response update(Patients person) {
    log.info("Inside UpdatePerson");
    log.info(person.getPersonId());
    dao = new PersonDaoImpl();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    person1 = dao.updatePerson(person);
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = mapper.writeValueAsString(person1);
        log.info("Person updated :: " + result);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.info("Exception Caught :: " + e);
    }
    if (person1 != null) {
        return Response.
                status(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()).
                entity(result).
                build();
    } else {
        return Response.
                status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode()).
                entity(result).
                build();
    }
}
```

UpdatePerson:

```
public Patients updatePerson(Patients updatedPatient) {

    Patients dbPatient = new Patients();
    TypedQuery<Patients> query = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        String identifier = updatedPatient.getPersonIdentifiers().getIdentifier();
        String queryStr = "SELECT c FROM Patients c where c.personIdentifiers.identifier = '" + identifier + "'";
        query = em.createQuery(queryStr, Patients.class);           
        dbPatient = query.getSingleResult();
        dbPatient.copy(updatedPatient);
        em.getTransaction().begin();            
        em.merge(dbPatient);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception caught :: " + e);
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        dbPatient = null;
    }
    em.close();
    return dbPatient;
}
```

I pass a json object through my REST api to create a patient entry:

```
{
"personId": 5,
"prefix": null,
"givenName": "Pooja roy",
"middleName": null
}
```

Now this is going fine. I take the same object, which now contains the auto-generated personId, in an api which is supposed to update the object. I pass the json in the Patients entity object. When I print this whole object, the personId is null.

Since it is null and primary key, I can't do a merge. I have to manually update the database object, which is a very lengthy process.

Any ideas why it is coming as null and how I can retrieve it?

I am using postgres.

Comment: Show your code. In particular, make sure you're saving the object returned from the `persist` call.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please elaborate the process a bit. You pass a JSON object to create a new Patient in your own  REST service? It saves it and returns the saved instance? And when you print it on the calling side there is no id?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not creating tables with the query. I am using JPA. I have entity classes which will create the table when I do persist.

Comment: @chrylis There are two separate APIs. One is addPatient one is updatePatient. The addPatient will take the json and save it in the DB and return the stored object. Here, in the response I can see the personId.

Comment: @chrylis In the updatePatient api, I am passing the same obj which I got from the addPatient response. In my code, I am  passing this json directly in Patients obj. I have added the REST api code. In the obj, when I do obj.getPersonId(), I get a null value.

Comment: The check what DDL your obfuscation layer creates. Maybe it fails to properly generate a `serial` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The id is getting generated and I am able to see it in the response. The same object (with the id) I am passing to another api like this : Patients pat; When I try to print the personId (patient.getPersonId()) I am getting null

Comment: @pirho While doing an addPatients, the id is getting generated and I am able to see it in the response and in the db. The same object (with the id) I am passing to another api like this : Patients pat; When I try to print the personId (patient.getPersonId()) I am getting null

Comment: so after `person1 = dao.updatePerson(person);` there is an id in `person1`? code for `PersonDaoImpl`?

Comment: Still no JPA API calls posted. So impossible to comment on lifecycle state of any object, what fields are loaded, or anything. What does your DEBUGGING tell you? you know, looking at the JPA providers LOG

Comment: @pirho PersonDaoImpl comes after. The problem is person.getPersonId() is null. It is coming as null before doing anything.

Comment: @pirho I have added the code to addPerson. Hope this clears things

Comment: @RubalJain id like to see `log.info(person1.getPersonId());` after `person1 = dao.updatePerson(person);` and code for `updatePerson()`.

Comment: @pirho In updatePerson() I'm getting the object from the database using one uuid and manually calling the setters for all the entries. So log.info(person1.getPersonId()); after person1 = dao.updatePerson(person); will give appropriate id. See the code for updatePerson()

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Please start from the beginning as “person”has a null Id could be referring to what you are reading in from JPA or what you are receiving from the json to patients conversion. Your query seems strange, as it should be on the Id, making me think it is your json conversion that is the issue, not JPA

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole problem is caused by the implementation of the `updatePerson` method. You should implement the method as follows and it should work as expected, assuming the `updatedPatient` instance is a persistent entity (meaning it has an ID field set):

```
public Patients updatePerson(Patients updatedPatient) {
    Patients mergedPatient = new Patients();

    try {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();            

        mergedPatient = em.merge(updatedPatient); 

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception caught :: " + e);
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    em.close();
    return mergedPatient;
}
```

Now `mergedPatient` should contain the synchronized state.

**Update:**

**alternative solution**

For whatever reason you cannot use a setter for the ID field. Then the following might solve your problem:

```
public Patients updatePerson(Patients updatedPatient) {

Patients dbPatient = new Patients();

    try {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        String identifier = updatedPatient.getPersonIdentifiers().getIdentifier();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        dbPatient = em.find(Patients.class, Long.parseLong(identifier));
        dbPatient.copy(updatedPatient);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ..:
        dbPatient = null;
    }
    em.close();
    return dbPatient;
}
```

As the `em.find()` method is executed inside of a transaction, the object returned is managed, which means any changes to that returned instance will be synchronized with the database when the transaction commits.

Comment: See that exactly is my problem. The updatedPatient is not having the personId. Otherwise I would have done the same thing.

Comment: If that is the case, you don't have to call the update method. And your JSON object has an id `5`; is that not a `personId`?

Comment: You mean I use a JSONParser or something like that to retrieve the id?

Comment: And yes, JSON object has the id, but I am not able to retrieve the id in my code. Thats the whole point. Please read the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

PersonId is an auto generated id. So, jpa doesn't allow for me to set a setter for personId. We only have getPersonId() method in the entity class.

So, in updatePerson(Patients person), when I am passing the person object, every setter is called and the object is thus created. Since, personId doesn't have a setter method, it is returned as null in that object.

Comment: "We only have getPersonId() method in the entity class": why don't you add a setter method instead of making things complicated?

Comment: I can't add a set method for personId. It creates multiple problems if I do so. Since it is an auto generated id, I don't a set method.

Comment: Sorry, I am not just trying to persuade you to do something you don't want. What I wanted to tell you is that JPA does not constrain to not use setter method and I don't see what problems it could create for you.

Comment: Auto generated has nothing to do with having a set method in JPA. It is a plain old java object and you can set any field you want with any value. You only get into problems if you try to persist it. You are talking about an update though, so it doesn’t fit why you need to set the ID value on an existing object. Where exactly in your process are you seeing the null id value, and how should it have been set?